# DRY react input handling causes cursor to jump

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dry

I was trying to DRY up my react forms a bit, so I wanted to move my basic input-handling function to a utility module and try to reuse it.  The idea was to update an object that represented the state, return it in a Promise, and then update the state locally in a quick one-liner.

**Component**

```
import handleInputChange from "./utility"

class MyInputComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data: {
                title: ""
            }
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <input
                type="text"
                id="title"
                value={this.state.data.title}
                onChange={e => handleInputChange(e, this.state).then(res => {
                    this.setState(res);
                })}
            />
        )
    }
};
```

**utility.js**

```
export const handleInputChange = (event, state) => {
    const { id, value } = event.target;
    return Promise.resolve({
        data: {
            ...state.data,
            [id]: value
        }
    });
};
```

It seems to work fine, however the issue is that the input's cursor always jumps to the end of the input.

If I use a normal local input handler and disregard being DRY, then it works fine.
For example, this works without issue regarding the cursor:

**Component**

```
class MyInputComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data: {
                title: ""
            }
        };
    }

    handleInputChange = event => {
        const { id, value } = event.target;

        this.setState({
            data: {
                ...this.state.data,
                [id]: value
            }
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <input
                type="text"
                id="title"
                value={this.state.data.title}
                onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            />
        )
    }
};
```

Any idea why the cursor issue would happen when I tried to be DRY?  Is the promise delaying the render, hence the cursor doesn't know where to go?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: The difference between the two is that in the `Promise` the `setState` will occur after the current execution frame is done by scheduling a (micro)`task`. It seems that in the case of `controlled components` this changes the browser behaviour. I don't really see the value of your `handleInput` function but you can still be DRY using function composition and keeping it synchronous : `handle = (state, cb) => (event) => (event.preventDefault(); cb({state, event.target })` (this could be a handler for `onSubmit` props).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little confused with what you are trying to do in the long run. If you want to be DRY maybe your react component could look like this

```
   render() {
    return (
        <input
            type={this.props.type}
            id={this.props.title}
            value={this.props.value}
            onChange={this.props.handleInputChange}
        />
    )
  }
```

this way you pass everything in and it stay stateless and everything is handle at a high component

however doing the way you have asked could you not use something like the below and you would not need to use a promise to return an object?

```
onChange={e => this.setState(handleInputChange(e, this.state))}
```

Comment: That makes sense.  The only point of doing this is because I have 15 components that do that same 7-8 lines of code.  So having it repeated 15 times felt dirty.  I wasn't sure of a good way to handle keeping my components DRY when in the end I HAVE to alter the state locally.

Comment: yes passing down a call back  or the last bit of code i added would help you stay DRY___ onChange={e => this.setState(handleInputChange(e, this.state))} ___ <--- that would take away the need for a promise but still keep it so you can import your function

Comment: Thank you!  I wasn't sure if this would fly, was a bad practice, etc.  I was trying to be too clever.  Simple is best.